# Error "commit failed" after upgrading to Hibernate 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to upgrade my project from version 3.6.10 to 4.3.6, and I am getting "commit failed" error on application start. Instead of using:

```
SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, allowCreate);
```

, for obtaining the session, now I am using:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Transactions are handled with TransactionManager, and Spring's NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource.

This is the stack trace that I am getting:

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#0' defined in class path resource [frontmvcSpringContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:561)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.setExecutionsInProgressInError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.doInvoke(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:187)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:557)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)
    ... 39 more
```

This is my session factory bean config:

```
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"  ref="DataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties"  ref="HibernateProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.` is the root of your problem. The connection to your database is not open.

Comment: I would bet that you are using the old hibernate session factory. Make sure you are creating your hibernate session with `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`. Can you post your session factory bean config?

Comment: I am using hibernate4 session factory, not sure why the connection is closing.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to remove "java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed." exception (that occurred with Hibernate 4) by commenting out line:

`<prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>`

in my session factory hibernate properties, in my Spring configuration xml.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Spring: [SPR-10395](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10395) - you should update it to version 3.2.3+